# How to connect multiple database in php project

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I am trying to connect multiple database in my project. Since i am using single database and it's working properly, now I would like to connect multiple 2 or 3 databse in my exisiting project, which will helpful for me. See my existing project code below for better understanding:

```
include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php');

Class Database{
 public $host   = DB_HOST;
 public $user   = DB_USER;
 public $pass   = DB_PASS;
 public $dbname = DB_NAME;
 
 
 public $link;
 public $error;
 
 public function __construct(){
  $this->connectDB();
 }
 
private function connectDB(){
 $this->link = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, 
  $this->dbname);
 if(!$this->link){
   $this->error ="Connection fail".$this->link->connect_error;
  return false;
 }
 }
}
```

Here is config.php file, where i will provide my multiple database connection credentials. Hence now here is single information given as I am using.

```
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "user");
define("DB_PASS", "pass");
define("DB_NAME", "db");
```

I have another file name called main.php where all the query operations functions are written. Here is the sample code:

```
include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/database.php');

    class Model
    {
        private $db;
    
        public function __construct()
        {
            
            $this->db = new Database();
        }
        public function employee_list()
        {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM emp_list ORDER BY emp_id DESC";
    
            return mysqli_query($this->db->link,$query);
        }
    }
```

Now I want to add multiple database with this existing project, so can you tell me whats need to update in this code. Thank you

Comment: You have declared the public properties of the `Database` class ( username,password etc ) using global constants rather than supplying them as variables to a constructor function and you can't redefine the constant later so you might wish to look at another approach?

Comment: I would modify your `Database` class to accept the database connection details as parameters, and then pass them in each time you create a new object of that class. Something like `$this->db1 = new Database(connection details)` repeated each time with different parameters.

Comment: But which I write my connection details everytime as parameters, I want to keep my connections in a single file so that I can change it from there if needed. Is it possible?

Comment: Do the different databases use different credentials ( username,password etc )?

Comment: yes I will include different credentials on config.php file for each of database.

Comment: You could certainly keep all the various database details within a single file but the approach above  will only work for a single database due to the use of the global constants rather than supplying the db connection details as parameters of the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already initialized the data members in your `Database` class with default values, you can make your constructor optionally accept the connection parameters, for example:

```
class Database
{
    public $host   = DB_HOST;
    public $user   = DB_USER;
    public $pass   = DB_PASS;
    public $dbname = DB_NAME;


    public $link;
    public $error;

    public function __construct(
        $host = NULL,
        $user = NULL,
        $pass = NULL,
        $dbname = NULL
    )
    {
        $this->host = $host ?? $this->host;
        $this->user = $user ?? $this->user;
        $this->pass = $pass ?? $this->pass;
        $this->dbname = $dbname ?? $this->dbname;
        
        $this->connectDB();
    }

    private function connectDB()
    {
        $this->link = new mysqli(
            $this->host,
            $this->user,
            $this->pass,
            $this->dbname
        );
        if (!$this->link) {
            $this->error = "Connection fail" . $this->link->connect_error;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This way, only changed values will be updated, so if you have two databases on the same host you can simply pass the `$dbname` parameter and leave the others unchanged.

```
$connection_1 = new Database();
$connection_2 = new Database(dbname: "my_other_database");
```

Another solution would be to leave your original code as is without changing it, but to include a different configuration file each time, it would still work fine.

Comment: @EyadMohammedOsama Do I need to connections detail as parameter? Do I need config.php file then how do I utilize that.

Comment: @LitonMazumder If you pass connection details as parameters, then you will get a dynamic approach that allows you to instantiate a database connection depending on a condition (for example). If you didn't like it, you can specify a different `config.php` file with other parameters and include it.

Comment: @EyadMohammedOsama I added line in config.php file for two connection, but I am bit confused how do I call this in my query operations page which is called main.php

`$connection_1 = new Database(host: "localhost", user: "user", pass: "pass",dbname: "db1");
$connection_2 = new Database(host: "localhost", user: "user", pass: "pass",dbname: "db2");`

Answer (score 0):

If you were to store **all** the database connection details in a single file ( as JSON ) you could do something like this.

```
<?php
    /*
        connection details for each database
        in JSON format. This could be saved
        as, for instance, db-credentials.json 
        -------------------------------------
        
        {
            "db1":{
                "dbuser":"dbo-764931",
                "dbhost":"localhost",
                "dbpwd":"xxx",
                "dbname":"blackrock"
            },
            "db2":{
                "dbuser":"dbo-984633",
                "dbhost":"localhost",
                "dbpwd":"xxx-yyy",
                "dbname":"area51"
            }
        }
        
    */
    
    
    
    
    class Database{
        private static $instance=false;
        private $db;
        
        private function __construct( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname ){
            mysqli_report( MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT );
            $this->db=new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );
        }
        public static function initialise( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname ){
            if( !self::$instance ) self::$instance=new self( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );
            return self::$instance;
        }
    }
    
    class Credentials{#class to read the db connection details for given $db
        private $json;
        private $db;
        
        public function __construct( $file, $db ){
            $this->json=file_exists( $file ) ? json_decode( file_get_contents( $file ) ) : false;
            $this->db=$db;
        }
        public function fetch(){
            return is_object( $this->json ) && property_exists( $this->json,$this->db ) ? $this->json->{$this->db} : false;
        }
    }
    
    class Model{
        private $db;
        private $config;
        
        public function __construct( $config,$db ){
            $credentials=new Credentials( $config,$db );
            $obj=$credentials->fetch();
            $this->db=Database::initialise( $obj->dbhost, $obj->dbuser, $obj->dbpwd, $obj->dbname );
        }
        public function employee_list(){
            $sql='SELECT * FROM emp_list ORDER BY emp_id DESC';
            return $this->db->query( $sql )->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );
        }
    }








    # only to show result
    function debug($obj){
        printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($obj,true));
    }








    $config = __DIR__ . '/db-credentials.json';

    $model_1=new Model( $config, 'db1' );
    $model_2=new Model( $config, 'db2' );
    
    
    debug( $model_1 );
    debug( $model_2 );
?>
```

Testing the above yields:

```
Model Object
(
    [db:Model:private] => Database Object
        (
            [db:Database:private] => mysqli Object
                (
                    [affected_rows] => 0
                    [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387 $
                    [client_version] => 50012
                    [connect_errno] => 0
                    [connect_error] => 
                    [errno] => 0
                    [error] => 
                    [error_list] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [field_count] => 0
                    [host_info] => localhost via TCP/IP
                    [info] => 
                    [insert_id] => 0
                    [server_info] => 5.5.8
                    [server_version] => 50508
                    [stat] => Uptime: 2210764  Threads: 3  Questions: 702637  Slow queries: 11  Opens: 12000  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 256  Queries per second avg: 0.317
                    [sqlstate] => 00000
                    [protocol_version] => 10
                    [thread_id] => 52276
                    [warning_count] => 0
                )

        )

    [config:Model:private] => 
)
```

... output for `$model_2` omitted.

With an approach like that you can edit the connection details without needing to modify the classes later and can use any number of different databases if required.